# How to navigate back in IOS?

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios

If I click on `Contact Us` link in my application, mail client will open. I don’t have back button to come back to my app.
I can navigate back in android using

```
((AndroidDriver) driver).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);
```

Is there any similar way in iOS to navigate back?

Comment: Please read the help center before posting

Comment: iOS puts a back button in the left side of the status bar for returning to the app that opened whatever app you're looking at.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any key like in Android to go back in iOS.
May be you can click x, y location of back button on the screen using
driver.tap function.

Answer (score 0):

User selenium navigate back it works in Appium also.

```
driver.navigate().back()
```

Comment: @T.Che : is the app support back function ?

Comment: it's only going to work if the app has a back button added from the development side. but if the user redirects to webview then I think only the relaunch app gonna help.

Answer (score 0):

**Xpath:**
private PointOption iosBackButtonLocationInUpperLeftCorner = PointOption.point(36, 36) //Specifically for iPhone 12 Pro Max

**Use this in your method:**
new TouchAction(driver).press(iosBackButtonLocationInUpperLeftCorner).release().perform()

Using appiums automator tool you can look up the coordinates of where the area is that you need to click back on. Sometimes for ios its in the status bar. Use the code above and plug in the coordinates you wish to tap. Should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.navigate().back();
```

This worked for me in iPhone 12 (14.5)